# zsh auto suggestion with vscode integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Problem:

- The zsh auto suggestion is very hard to see.
- I tried to

```
"terminal.background" : "#000000", 
"terminal.foreground" : "#00FD61",
```

change the background and foreground.

How to override the default color of zsh auto-suggestion in vs-code integrated terminal.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
"terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#ff0000"
```